# How can factory's have access to other factory's products in abstract factory pattern

Tags: c#, abstract-factory

[image: Here is a diagram of the pattern im referring to.]

In this example for the NYPizzaIngredientFactory, they can only make pizza with ThinCrustDough. How can i make a pizza that could use another factory's ingredients like ThickCrustDough from ChicagoPizzaIngredientFactory. I want to try stay away from builder and stick with abstract factory patterns and factory methods.

Comment: You can't, that is how the class diagram is designed (for example, FreshClams isn't available in Chicago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NYPizzaStore` would have to use the `ChicagoPizzaIngredientFactory` if you want it to be able to use `ThickCrustDough`.

If you think about the practicality of this, however, it probably doesn't make sense to have them ship you the ingredients from Chicago.

In my mind, you have two options:

1. Have another factory located in NY that can produce thick dough (e.g. `NYThickPizzaIngredientFactory`). This is because your interface has a single `createDough` method that takes no arguments so you can't tell it what type of dough to make. It can only make one.
2. Alter your interface so that the `createDough` method accepts arguments that can tell the factory what type of dough to create. **This is the one I would recommend**.

The type of arguments can also be based on the particular factory. For instance:

```
//TDoughArts tells you what type of arguments the factory needs in order to make dough.
public interface IPizzaIngredientFactory<TDoughArgs> where TDoughArgs : IDoughArgs      
{
    //....
    IDough CreateDough(TDoughArgs doughArgs);
    //....
}

public interface IDoughArgs
{

}

public class NYPizzaDoughArgs : IDoughArgs
{
    public enum DoughTypes
    {
        Thin = 0,
        Thick = 1
    }

    public DoughTypes DoughType { get; set; }
}

public class NYPizzaIngredientFactory : IPizzaIngredientFactory<NYPizzaDoughArgs>
{
    //....
    public IDough CreateDough(NYPizzaDoughArgs doughArgs)
    {
        //Make the right dough based on args here
        if(doughArgs.DoughType == DoughTypes.Thin)
            //...
    }
    //....
}
```

I whipped this out in a few minutes so check for consistency, but I think you will get the idea.

You don't have to use generics. You can simply stick with the `IDoughArgs` interface if you don't want more specificity.

Usage:

```
var factory = new NYPizzaIngredientFactory();
var args = new NYPizzaDoughArgs();
args.DoughType = NYPizzaDoughArgs.DoughTypes.Thick;
var dough = factory.createDough(args);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is this:

```
public interface IDoughArgs
{

}

public class NYPizzaDoughArgs : IDoughArgs
{
    public enum DoughTypes
    {
        Thin = 0,
        Thick = 1
    }

    public DoughTypes DoughType { get; set; }
}
```

`IDoughArgs` has no members. The class that implements it, `NYPizzaDoughArgs`, has properties which are not implementations of `IDoughArgs`. That renders the `IDoughArgs` interface meaningless.

Additionally, look at this class declaration:

```
public class NYPizzaIngredientFactory : IPizzaIngredientFactory<NYPizzaDoughArgs>
```

What class is going to "know" the generic argument and know to create this class as opposed to some other generic implementation? It's going to get confusing when you get to that part. You'll need some sort of factory to create your factory.

Then, if you decide that ingredient factories vary by more than just the type of dough, and you need more generic arguments, it's going to get really messy.

And, what happens if, in addition to having options such as thickness that are specific to just one dough type, you need options that are specific to just one thickness? Perhaps thick dough is only an option if you've selected New York or Chicago style (not European) and stuffed crust is only an option if you've selected a thick crust. That's going to get really difficult to describe with interfaces. It sounds more like data.

Here's a stab at another way to implement this:

```
public  enum PizzaStyle 
{
    NewYork = 1,
    Chicago = 2,
    Greek = 4
}

public enum CrustType 
{
    Thick = 1024,
    Thin = 2048,
    HandTossed = 4096
}

public enum CrustOption
{
    Stuffed = 32768
}

public enum PizzaDoughOption
{
    NewYorkThin = PizzaStyle.NewYork + CrustType.Thin,
    NewYorkHandTossed = PizzaStyle.NewYork + CrustType.HandTossed,
    NewYorkThick = PizzaStyle.NewYork + CrustType.Thick,
    NewYorkThickStuffed = NewYorkThick + CrustOption.Stuffed,
    ChicagoThin = PizzaStyle.Chicago + CrustType.Thin,
    ChicagoHandTossed = PizzaStyle.Chicago + CrustType.HandTossed,
    ChicagoThick = PizzaStyle.Chicago + CrustType.Thick,
    ChicagoThickStuffed = ChicagoThick + CrustOption.Stuffed,
    Greek = PizzaStyle.Greek // only comes one way?
}
```

There are other ways to represent this same data. Even if there were fifty values in the `PizzaDoughOption` enumeration, it's probably still easier that way, building a definitive, readable list of valid options, as opposed to trying to represent that in code with a bunch of branches. (If you want to unit test that, you'll end up coding every single combination anyway in unit tests.)

And there are several ways you could use this data. You could present just a big list of options. You could allow users to select from the various options and, as you go, determine whether it matches a valid combination. Or they could select any option and you could narrow the list of options according to which include the desired option. (You want a stuffed crust? Ok, that's either New York thick crust or Chicago thick crust.)

Now, if you need a factory to create dough according to type, you could do this:

```
public interface IDoughFactory
{
    Dough GetDough(PizzaDoughOption doughOption);
}
```

The implementation might look something like this. To be honest I might use a "factory factory" here, but for now since there are only three types I'll keep it simpler.

```
public class DoughFactory : IDoughFactory
{
    // Each of these also implement IDoughFactory
    private readonly NewYorkDoughFactory _newYorkDoughFactory;
    private readonly ChicagoDoughFactory _chicagoDoughFactory;
    private readonly GreekDoughFactory _greekDoughFactory;

    public DoughFactory(
        NewYorkDoughFactory newYorkDoughFactory,
        ChicagoDoughFactory chicagoDoughFactory,
        GreekDoughFactory greekDoughFactory)
    {
        _newYorkDoughFactory = newYorkDoughFactory;
        _chicagoDoughFactory = chicagoDoughFactory;
        _greekDoughFactory = greekDoughFactory;
    }

    public Dough GetDough(PizzaDoughOption doughOption)
    {
        if (MatchesPizzaStyle(doughOption, PizzaStyle.NewYork)) 
            return _newYorkDoughFactory.GetDough(doughOption);
        if (MatchesPizzaStyle(doughOption, PizzaStyle.Chicago)) 
            return _chicagoDoughFactory.GetDough(doughOption);
        if (MatchesPizzaStyle(doughOption, PizzaStyle.Greek)) 
            return _greekDoughFactory.GetDough(doughOption);
        // Throw an exception or return a default dough type. I'd throw the exception.
    }

    private bool MatchesPizzaStyle(PizzaDoughOption doughOption, PizzaStyle pizzaStyle)
    {
        return ((int) doughOptions & (int) pizzaStyle) == (int) pizzaStyle;
    }
}
```

Now your more concrete dough factories (New York, Chicago, Greek) all receive the same `PizzaDoughOption`. If they care whether thin or thick has been selected, they can handle it. If that option doesn't exist they can ignore it. Even if something has gone wrong in an outer class and somehow someone has invoked `GreekDoughFactory` with the `StuffedCrust` option, it won't fail. It just ignores it.

What would be the possible point to all of this?

First, the class creating a pizza has no knowledge of the intricacies of creating the right dough type. It just depends on a dough factory, passes a parameter, and gets the right dough. That's simple and testable.

Second, you don't have to call `new` anywhere. You can employ dependency injection all the way down. That way the class that depends on the abstract `IDoughFactory` doesn't know anything about what dependencies `DoughFactory` has.

Likewise, maybe the concrete dough factories have dependencies of their own and they differ significantly from one to the next. As long as those are getting resolved from the container and injected into `DoughFactory`, that's fine, and `DoughFactory` won't know anything about their dependencies.

All of the dependencies are wired up in your DI container, but the classes themselves are small, simple, and testable, depending on abstractions and not coupled to implementations of anything.

Someone might look and this and think it's a little more complicated. What's critical is that not only does it keep individual classes decoupled, but it leaves a path forward for future change. The design of your classes, which shouldn't have to change too much, won't closely mirror the details of specific types of pizzas, which can and should change. You don't want to have to re-architect your pizza application because of a new kind of pizza.